# Finding Log4j instances on Windows 2012R2

Tags: windows, security, windows-server-2012-r2, log4j

I have not been able to find any good information on the MS website at present for 2012r2 log4j detection. It appears the Windows Defender is supposed to detect issues but is not properly supported for 2012r2. Does anyone have any quick check tools that they recommend?

Comment: You need to track your code in order to know where you may be running log4j, or if you bought software from elsewhere you need to talk to the developer. Is this a web server? And application server? Are you hoping the OS can find vulnerable code in 3rd party software running on the server?

Comment: A webserver yes. I am not overly familiar with log4j but I assume it is some sort of library - is it not feasible to locate this without diving into third party code?

Comment: As the one running the software, you need to know what is being run. If you didn't write the software you need to talk to the people who did write it. However, you have admitted to not being aware of what you're even looking for. You need to start by doing research. You're asking us to do your work for you, and you're asking is Microsoft will do your work for you checking for this vulnerability.

Comment: Like I said I have been unable to find any good information online for how to detect on this O/S. I'm asking if anyone in a similar boat has had a solution. It is not the case that there is 2 pieces of software running on here that I can just peer through. I've inherited the servers from previous admin and it is not a simple task to prepare a finite list of applications to investigate, hence why i asked if there is a tool which can look for these vulnerabilities.

Comment: “ I'm asking if anyone in a similar boat has had a solution.” - That isn’t how this website works. We can not give you a list of software you are running that is vulnerable to that particular exploit

Comment: @Ramhound, that wasn't my question. I was asking whether there is a particular piece of software that can be run on a Windows machine to locate/scan any vulnerabilities. Like I said, on the MS website it shows the steps for using Windows Defender to locate them, but it is not properly supported on 2012r2 - hence why I am asking if there are any other recognised products which do so.

Comment: The [log4jfinder](https://github.com/fox-it/log4j-finder) also works on Windows, but there is one restriction:  it only scans the drive your current working directory is on in the cmd/powershell you start it from (so you have to execute it separately for every drive).